# what exactly is database schema?

Tags: sql-server

I am new in the CS field, and one thing is that before asking this question I already googled it, but that made me more confused between two definitions I have found, so I'm asking which one is correct?
So in this link, I found multiple answers which one is correct? 
[What is the purpose of database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674222/what-is-purpose-of-database-schema)

I found this. What's confusing for me I think is that they both definitions are different from each other Guide me..

1) A SQL schema is container of objects. For example, you may have a large enterprise application and then it's a good practice to use different schemas for different purposes (e.g. put HR related tables into HR schema, accounting related tables into Accounting schema and so on). A schema can be owned by any user, and the ownership is transferable.

2)the database schema is the definition that describes the entire configuration of the database, including all of its tables, relations, index, etc

my question is different I have read the multiple answers which are available but I found multiple answers that is what made me more confused

Comment: See https://blog.quest.com/using-database-schemas-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct. "Schema" has multiple meanings. Your first meaning is the kind of schema you get with `CREATE SCHEMA` -- an object container. Your second meaning is the general meaning of "database schema" that's independent of SQL Server. Usually it's clear from context which meaning is intended -- "database schema" is typically singular, while "schemas" within a single database refer to the containers. So, if you wanted to be particularly confusing, you could talk about a database schema<sub>2</sub> that has multiple schemas<sub>1</sub> in it.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly speaking, `Schema` is the synonym for `database instance`

You can use both `CREATE SCHEMA MYDATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE MYDATABASE` in relational database such as MySql to create a new database instance.

The word `Schema` was once thought to be too academic and somewhat later obsoleted.

Both are Okey, but `Schema` sounds a little geek.

Comment: What you're saying is true specifically for MySQL (the question is about SQL Server). In MySQL, `SCHEMA` is a syntactical synonym for `DATABASE`. However, even for MySQL databases, it would be normal to talk about the database schema without confusing it with the database itself -- this is an abstract concept that's independent of the database system used (whereas SQL Server schemas are an implementation detail).